# Use Euler's Criterion to deduce that $5^{2^{2^{n}-1}}\equiv -1 \space \text{mod} \space p $

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be a prime and suppose $$p=2^{2^{n}}+1$$
for some $n \ge 2$.

Use Euler's  Criterion to deduce that $$5^{2^{2^{n}-1}}\equiv -1 \space \text{mod} \space p  $$

I am not sure how Euler's criterion would help in this situation, even though I have been told to use it.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you even attempted to apply Euler's criterion?  What's the value of $(p-1)/2$ in this case?

Comment: So if we have $\left(\frac{5}{p}\right) \equiv 5^{2^{2^{n}-1}} \text{mod}\space p$, is it sufficient to show that $\left(\frac{5}{p}\right) \equiv -1 \text{mod} \space p$?

Comment: Yes, it is sufficient. Basically, the problem reduces to showing that $5$ is a quadratic nonresidue modulo $p$

Answer (score 1):

Applying Euler's criterion reduces the problem to showing that $5$ is not a quadratic residue mod $p$

Then, using Gauss' reciprocity law reduces to showing that $p$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $5$

This is easy to show since,

$$p=2^{2^n}+1\equiv 2^{2^n\bmod 4}+1\equiv 2^0+1\equiv 2\pmod 5$$

and $2$ is not a quadratic residue mod $5$ (only $0,1,4$ are).